# Does Windows Media Foundation on UWP have a resampler? If so how do I use it?

Tags: audio, uwp, ms-media-foundation

Using Win32 I have access to `CLSID_CResamplerMediaObject` which means I can reduce my channel count from say 6 to 2.

On UWP this is no longer defined and the only reference to a resampler I can find is `CLSID_AudioResamplerMediaObject`. When I create an instance of this class however, and pass it my `MFMediaType_Float` or `MFMediaType_PCM` type, it says that the provided types aren't supported...

```
ComPtr<IUnknown> pTransformUnknown = nullptr;
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AudioResamplerMediaObject, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUnknown, &pTransformUnknown));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(pTransformUnknown->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&mResampler)));

IMFMediaType* pInputType = nullptr;
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(MFCreateMediaType(&pInputType));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(pInputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(pInputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM)); // Or MFAudioFormat_Float
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(pInputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(pInputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, 6));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(pInputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, 48000));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(mAudioSourceReader->SetCurrentMediaType(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, nullptr, pInputType)); // Fails here!
```

As usual, Microsoft docs aren't helpful, I would appreciate any help!

Input file is Mp4 with 1 aac stream, 6 channels, 16 bit audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLSID_AudioResamplerMediaObject` and `CLSID_CResamplerMediaObject` are the same thing, same GUID of {f447b69e-1884-4a7e-8055-346f74d6edb3}.

The error you mentioned is not coming from audio resampler, you have it from Source Reader API. The error is presumably correctly reported indicating the situation that for given media source the reader cannot provide a conversion to supplied media type. There can be multiple reasons for this to happen.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to investigate further then.

Comment: Turns out I was missing: MF_MT_AUDIO_CHANNEL_MASK, MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND... They're all compulsory attributes.

Comment: Correct. They are basically described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/aac-decoder) and, in general case, one would want to know what media type exactly is suggested by decoder and request it from source reader. Another possible method is to request partial media type.